# Regular expression token antlrV3

Tags: parsing, antlr, expression, token, lexer

Can I write a rule where the initial token is partly fixed and partly generic?

```
rule: ID '=' NUMBER
      ;

ID: (A.. Z | a.. Z) +

NUMBER: (0 .. 9) +
```

But only if the token ID is in the form var* (var is fixed)

Thanks

Comment: What does *'But only if the token ID is in the form var\* (in regular expression where var is fixed)'* mean?

Comment: I need a parser for code like this:

varA = 3
vare = 5
varDF = 3
...

where var is fixed, otherwise I will be notified an exception

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, then 280Z28 has answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
// Use this instead of ID in all parser rules that take either token
identifier
    :   VAR_ID | ID
    ;

VAR_ID
    :   'var' ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')*
    ;

ID
    :   ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')+
    ;
```

**Either way**: when possible, do ***NOT*** use a strict lexer grammar for your error messages. They are *slower* and *completely illegible to users*. You should parse `ID` in a relaxed form, then check later on if it's in precisely the correct form.

Comment: Thank you. But the token ID is present in other rules and I need that it remains generic.

Comment: @Boo: If you follow my *strong* suggestion, it would remain general anyway.

Comment: is just what I need if you say you do it in the parser. Please keep me you could post an example? I'm not an expert in ANTLR ... Thank you very much.